# how to remove the white space between two span tags?

Tags: html, css

```css
    .side-bar{
        background-color: red; 
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px){
        .side-bar{
            z-index:10;
            position:absalute;
            width:220px;
            /*padding-top:60px;*/
            height:100%;
            /*top:0;*/
            position:fixed;

    }
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px){
        .top-left-part{
            width:220px;
            position:fixed;
            z-index: 11;
            /*top: 0;*/
            height: 60px;
        }
    }
    /*---------------top left part starts here------------*/
    .top-left-part{
        width:220px;
        float:left;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        /*padding-top: 60px;*/
    }
    .top-left-image{
        float: left;
        height: 40px;
        width: 50px;
        padding-left: 1.3px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-top: 2.7px;
    }
    .left-top-text{
        display: inline-block;
        padding-top:6px;
        font-size: 30px;
        white-space: nowrap;
       /* word-spacing: -1px;
       /* float: right;*/
        /*margin-left: 10px;*/
    }
    .text-elite{
        font-weight: 600;
    }
    .text-admin{
        padding-left: -5px;
    }
    /*---------------top left part ends here-------------*/
    /*---------------top-right part starts here----------*/
    .top-right-part{
        top: 0 !important;
        background-color:#4F5467;
        width:100%;
        height:60px;
        right: 0;
    }
    .arrow-left{
        color: white;
    }
    /*---------------top right part ends here-------------*/
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
              <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
              <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/elite.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="js/elite.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="top-bar">
            <div class="top-left-part">
                <span ><img src="img/elite-icon.jpg" class="top-left-image"> </span>
                <span class="left-top-text text-elite">elite </span>
                <span class="left-top-text text-admin">admin</span>
            </div>
            <div class="top-right-part">
                <span class="arrow-left fa-arrow-left"> </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom-part">
            <div id="left-side-bar" class="side-bar">

            </div>
            <div id="right-side-container">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

on above code I have two span tag elements: elite and admin. I want to remove space between them. I tried to put negative value for padding property of second span element, but it's not working. how can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: Just remove space between span html tags

Comment: just add `font-size:0;` to parent element of a span

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update Css**

```
.left-top-text {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 6px;
    font-size: 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
```

**Snippet Example**

```css
.side-bar{
        background-color: red; 
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px){
        .side-bar{
            z-index:10;
            position:absalute;
            width:220px;
            /*padding-top:60px;*/
            height:100%;
            /*top:0;*/
            position:fixed;

    }
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px){
        .top-left-part{
            width:220px;
            position:fixed;
            z-index: 11;
            /*top: 0;*/
            height: 60px;
        }
    }
    /*---------------top left part starts here------------*/
    .top-left-part{
        width:220px;
        float:left;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        /*padding-top: 60px;*/
    }
    .top-left-image{
        float: left;
        height: 40px;
        width: 50px;
        padding-left: 1.3px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-top: 2.7px;
    }
   .left-top-text {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 6px;
    font-size: 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-left: -5px;
   }
    .text-elite{
        font-weight: 600;
    }
    .text-admin{
        padding-left: -5px;
    }
    /*---------------top left part ends here-------------*/
    /*---------------top-right part starts here----------*/
    .top-right-part{
        top: 0 !important;
        background-color:#4F5467;
        width:100%;
        height:60px;
        right: 0;
    }
    .arrow-left{
        color: white;
    }
    /*---------------top right part ends here-------------*/
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
              <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
              <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/elite.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="js/elite.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="top-bar">
            <div class="top-left-part">
                <span ><img src="img/elite-icon.jpg" class="top-left-image"> </span>
                <span class="left-top-text text-elite">elite </span>
                <span class="left-top-text text-admin">admin</span>
            </div>
            <div class="top-right-part">
                <span class="arrow-left fa-arrow-left"> </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom-part">
            <div id="left-side-bar" class="side-bar">

            </div>
            <div id="right-side-container">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems like a hacky solution - what if the font size changes, then you will need to change the margin

Comment: Giving a negative value is not a proper way

Comment: @Dhaarani Giving negative value to a post is a way to express communities disagreement with the answer. Don't take it personally. After all, the points you get here are just imaginary ones.

Answer (score 23):

Jordi Flores is right. Inline (and inline-block) elements are rendered like text characters, meaning a space or a newline in the HTML code will result in a space in the rendered output. You just have to remove the formatting characters in the code to fix this.

If you want to keep your code organized, you can use HTML comments. For ex:

```
<div>
   <span>My span 1</span><!-- 
--><span>My span 2</span><!--
--><span>My span 3</span><!--
--><span>My span 4</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Just Remove space between html tags

```css
    .side-bar{
        background-color: red; 
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px){
        .side-bar{
            z-index:10;
            position:absalute;
            width:220px;
            /*padding-top:60px;*/
            height:100%;
            /*top:0;*/
            position:fixed;

    }
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px){
        .top-left-part{
            width:220px;
            position:fixed;
            z-index: 11;
            /*top: 0;*/
            height: 60px;
        }
    }
    /*---------------top left part starts here------------*/
    .top-left-part{
        width:220px;
        float:left;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        /*padding-top: 60px;*/
    }
    .top-left-image{
        float: left;
        height: 40px;
        width: 50px;
        padding-left: 1.3px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-top: 2.7px;
    }
    .left-top-text{
        display: inline-block;
        padding-top:6px;
        font-size: 30px;
        white-space: nowrap;
       /* word-spacing: -1px;
       /* float: right;*/
        /*margin-left: 10px;*/
    }
    .text-elite{
        font-weight: 600;
    }
    .text-admin{
        padding-left: -5px;
    }
    /*---------------top left part ends here-------------*/
    /*---------------top-right part starts here----------*/
    .top-right-part{
        top: 0 !important;
        background-color:#4F5467;
        width:100%;
        height:60px;
        right: 0;
    }
    .arrow-left{
        color: white;
    }
    /*---------------top right part ends here-------------*/
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
              <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
              <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/elite.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="js/elite.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="top-bar">
            <div class="top-left-part">
                <span ><img src="img/elite-icon.jpg" class="top-left-image"> </span>
                <span class="left-top-text text-elite">elite </span><span class="left-top-text text-admin">admin</span>
            </div>
            <div class="top-right-part">
                <span class="arrow-left fa-arrow-left"> </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom-part">
            <div id="left-side-bar" class="side-bar">

            </div>
            <div id="right-side-container">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: but this is so annoying, especially if code editor formats your code :S

Answer (score 7):

just give `font-size: 0;` to .top-left-part and try....

```
.top-left-part {
   width: 220px;
   float: left;
   background-color: #ffffff;
/* padding-top: 60px; */
   font-size: 0;
 }
```

Actually by default display inline-block will create one invisible node between the elements so we need to remove that node giving `font-size: 0` to the parent element. And you have to give font-size to your child elements.

Comment: Not crossbowser solution.

Comment: At least Opera 12. As I heard, some chinese versions of Chromium-based browsers too.

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS like this - this should work.

```
.text-admin{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
```

**`<span>`** elements are inline-elements, means that it's width depends on it's content. Paddings and margins aren't applied. To "enable" support for margins and paddings, you have to change the span to render as inline-block element. (with `display: inline-block;`). After this you can apply a negative margin of e.g. 4px to reduce the gap between your elements.