# Put 2 tags <span> in one line and two lines

Tags: html, css

I put 2  tags in one line, the text displays normally, 
but putting in two lines, I have a small space between them

ps: no styling for them

```html
<span>Text1</span>
<span>Text2</span>
<span>Text1</span><span>Text2</span>
```

---

[image]

Comment: Could you give us more details? Is this HTML inside a framework or something? Can you share a screenshot of the "space between them"?

Comment: I updated the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEo5d.png

Comment: @disinfor The answer in the link you gave has a negative value.

Comment: @Gosi It's not the accepted answer. Scroll down to the answer by Simon. That's exactly what the OPs issue is. Sometimes you have to look at other answers.

Comment: @disinfor Link that particular answer then.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39571751/2518317

Answer (score 0):

This is just how html works, that line betwixt the two `<span>`s counts as content (and since whitespace [normally] collapses, your newline+indent becomes a single space).

The only way around it is to somehow *not have the line separating them*.
You can do this with another tag, having the two tags touch, or cheekily use a comment.
None look nice in the code, but that's how it works.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39571751/2518317

```
    <span>text</span><!--
 --><span>text2</span>
```

Comment: Since you just posted the answer from a duplicate, could you vote to close this question instead of posting a new answer?

Comment: I wrote it then found the duplicate and added the link afterward, I'll let others handle that

Comment: That's fine, but I would still put in a close vote so it can remove questions that already have answers.

Comment: true, done. I just wanted to make sure they have a response in a legible manner at least before the close. That particular question is a mess for someone new

Comment: Agreed, since the accepted answer is essentially useless.